# Transferring Domain To Point at Hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I've never done this before but I assumed it was a simple process.  I've got a domain whose nameservers are with zoneedit, and therefore managed from there, but their IPS tag is with 123-reg, and the hosting is also with 123-reg.  I set everything up correctly and all worked fine pointing at our old hosting using zoneedit, however the moment I changed the IP addresses to point at the new hosting instead of going to the new site, it redirected to the 123-reg site.  The IP addresses were *definitely* correct (I had people assuming I just pinged 123-reg and used that IP address, which isn't the case).

Is there something I'm missing here?  It worked fine on the old hosting, but doesn't work with the new hosting.  I've now had to set up a web forwarder which isn't ideal.

Any ideas? I'm a bit clueless on this front.

Answer (score 0):

The webserver on the hosting side needs to know about the domains pointing to it. Only than can it differentiate between the various websites (eg looking at the hostheaders and making decisions based on them)

Comment: Would using the hostings nameservers be of benefit when pointing it at the hosting? i.e. eliminate this problem? The nameservers have just changed now actually, so it's in their control now (even though I manage it)